# Trying to check MySQL database with java, jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am trying to print some data from my database in Mysql using some classes in java and jsp. It's my first time doing this. I googled a lot but nothing helped me. Here is my code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <form action="DB_results.jsp">
        <input type = "submit" value = "Database">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Draw.java**

```
package DB_draw;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Draw {
    ResultSet myRs;

    public ResultSet getMyRs() {
        return myRs;
    }

    public void setMyRs() {
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tst","root","");

            Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();

            this.myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("select * from tst.people");

            while (this.myRs.next())
            {
                System.out.println(this.myRs.getString("onoma") + " " + this.myRs.getString("epitheto") + " " + this.myRs.getInt("id"));
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**DB_results.jsp**

```
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
<%@ page import="DB_draw.*" %>

<jsp:useBean id="DB_draw" class="DB_draw.Draw" scope="session" />
<jsp:setProperty name="DB_draw" property="*"/>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Database</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:black">
<div style = "color:yellow; font-family:fantasy; font-size:30px">
     <%
        ResultSet myRs = DB_draw.getMyRs(); 
        if(myRs == null) out.println("Problem");
        else
            while(myRs.next())
            {
                out.println(myRs.getString("onoma") + " " + myRs.getString("epitheto") + " " + myRs.getInt("id"));
            }
     %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The Problem is that when i try to print the results in DB_results.jsp using variable myRs, myRs == NULL. Why is this happening? I'm using Tomcat-Apache 8.0.

Answer (score 1):

You never call `setMyRS()`. And even if you did, `setMyRS()` iterates through the resultset, so `myRs.next()` would always return false in the JSP.

Comment: I have tried the same code as above, just to write a string in an input of an html form , i never called setter in my jsp, but when i called my getter I got the string that i wrote in my html form. It was weird but i thought it worked fine. I'm all alone in this. Can you guide me how to call my setter and where? Thank you!

Comment: Call it before calling getMyRS(), since otherwise, getMyRS() returns null. Or create and return the RS from getMyRS() and remove the setMyRS() method. Why would you need a field to store the result set? Also, setMyRS() is not a setter. A setter takes an argument. Finally, read about MVC. You should never have Java code in a JSP. jsp:useBean should not be used anymore. jsp:setProperty even less. You're programming as if we were in 1999.

Comment: I tried both of what you have suggested. Still the same problem. I know that the issue is in setting the Resultset as you said the first time.